# Ubuntu 20/PulseAudio - Speaker is set as an input

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio

I have a Dell u3419W plugged in. And I can't seem to get the speakers to work. Upon doing `pacmd list-sources` and `pacmd list-sinks`, it seems like it was listed under a source rather than a sink. Just wondering how I can switch it so it's recognized properly.

System:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Xmonad
- Thinkpad X1 Carbon

Comment: Welcome! Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `pacmd list-sources` and `pcmd list-sinks`?